# Dolphin file manager: How to highlight active tab

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, dolphin

In kubuntu 20.04 / plasma 5.18.5, with the Dolphin file manager split view I find the difference between active and inactive tab is too small.

How to customise the apperance of the active tab?